# Java-Where to use wait in Consumer

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a producer-consumer pgm. Shared resource is queue (Array of Objects-size 5). Producer adds an Object and notifies Consumer,when the q is full waits.Consumer waits when the q is empty else reads/removes and notifies producer that it is done.

What am not able to understand is

1. When the Producer notifies after adding obj, the consumer will not be in waiting state so the producer keeps producing till the q is full.

Could anybody plz help how to overcome this. I know somewhere simple am missing but not able to fig out:(

```
class Queue
{
  public void add(Object item) 
  {
   q[index] = item;
   index++;
  }
  public Object get()
  { 
   Object item = q[index - 1];
   index--;
   return item;
  }
  public boolean isQfull()
  {
System.out.println("Queue:index-->" + index);
if(index == 5)
{
 return true;
}
return false;
  }

  public boolean isQEmpty()
  {
   if(index == 0)
{
 System.out.println("Queue:isQEmpty");
 return true;           
}
 return false;
  }
}

class Producer extends Thread 
{
 public void run()
 {
  synchronized(q)
  {
   for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
    if(q.isQfull())
    {
     q.wait();
    }
    else
    {
     q.add(i);                      
     q.notify();                        
    }
   }
 }
}
public class Consumer extends Thread
{
 public void run()
 {
  synchronized(q)
  {
   while(true)
{
 if(q.isQEmpty())
 {
  q.wait();                     
 }
 else
 {
 System.out.println("Consumer consuming" + q.get());
 q.notify();
}
   }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the consumer code?

Comment: synchronization should belong in the queue code, not in the things accessing it.

Comment: An observation:  what you've got here is a stack and not a queue.  And a theory:  I'm starting to wonder if your empty/full predicates are faulty--what's the code for those?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Have you considered using a queue from the java concurrent package?  You won't have to manually synchronize the producer and consumer.

EDIT:

In that case you could forget about synchronizing your producer and consumer.  Instead, have your Queue class synchronize its add and get calls.

```
class Queue
private final Object lock = new Object();
{
  public void add(Object item) 
  {
    synchronized(lock) {
      q[index] = item;
      index++;
    }
  }
  public Object get()
  { 
    synchronized(lock) {
      Object item = q[index - 1];
      index--;
      return item;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better example of how to do an add() and get() implementation (synchronizing the service entity or repository - not those calling the functions).

Comment: @kushi - What doesn't it solve?  Your producer and consumer do not need to notify each other.  Have your consumer sit in a loop and wait for queue to have items to retrieve.  Have your producer sit in another loop and wait if the queue is full, otherwise add new items.  Remove the synchronized code in the producer and consumer and remove the q.notify() call.

Answer (score 1):

This question needs re-wording but I believe the question is (related to what looks like a homework assignment)...

"What am not able to understand is 1)When the Producer notifies after adding obj,the consumer will not be in waiting state so the producer keeps producing till the q is full.Could anybody plz help how to overcome this."

The logic for the Producer class seems clear and the implementation reasonably correct. That is, the Producer does not care about the Consumer activity only in so much as the Queue remains full. Presuming the Thread is run() periodically to re-fill the Queue that the Consumers are removing entries from, the Producer should not wait() but simply exit if the Queue is full.

Thus:

```
if (!q.isFull())
 ... add to queue and notify Consumers.
```

What is missing here is the Consumer side that needs to wait() or check-back periodically if the queue is empty (waiting for the Producer to replenish the Queue).

Comment: @Darrell-->First its not home-work/assignment:) was just playing around dis 4m a long tym:( Hve updated Consumer class also dunno how did i forget:(

Comment: Okay - if this solved it, go ahead and mark this as answered. Cheers.

Comment: The code sample is incomplete and does not show the implementation of Queue.isQfull(), which could be where the problem lies. Would recommend use of Atomics however to handle the synchronization of the Queue item references.

Comment: @Darrell-->Have included isQfull() and isQEmpty()

Comment: Code sample will not compile, the Queue.notify() should probably be Queue.get() in the Consumer, etc. The bounds of the queue vary by 20 in the Producer and 5 in the Queue for the determination of 'full'. The Queue methods should be synchronized, not in the Producer or Consumer. There are multiple issues in the sample code not really leading to a question to be answered. Recommend simply asking how to implement a simple Producer/Consumer queue versus fixing each issue present.

Comment: @Darrell-->the Q/Array's size is 5... Instead of using while(true) in Producer,I have iterated for 1ly 20 times.. nd the code is compiling well.. After trying out 1ly I had posted it.. I cannot post the entire code.. So have posted the main areas of interest...